# A word for feeling simultaneously anxious & calm

Tags: single-word-requests, emotions

I'm searching for a word that means feeling both scared and relaxed at the same time. The reason why is because I'm looking for music that evokes particular emotions I can't describe.

Here are some examples:

> C418 - Chirp (SLOWED) - *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOrsad_cXOQ*

> Nichijou OST - Helvetica Standard Sono 3 -  *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YBTCkJrerM*

> Small Shock (SLOWED) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqWixE_2_CE

> Tonight You Belong To Me (SLOWED) -  *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl1FBIIb03s&list=PL7l59LvQNSCrShhnDn5OQ83onhID5wWZl&index=6*

> Instupendo - Six Forty Seven - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHlcmmkiwbU&list=PL7l59LvQNSCrShhnDn5OQ83onhID5wWZl&index=3

All of these songs evoke the same emotions that are too tricky for me to pin point. But I do know they are all relaxing yet unnerving in their own unique way.

Comment: In the last sentence, you might want to find a better term than _chilling_ as that is often used as a synonym for relaxing.

Comment: @KillingTime Oh thank you I didn't see that! Ill change it to *unnerving*.

Comment: I listened to two of the songs and I'm afraid that I don't get it. Song one was slightly tense; song four was wistful (only the background picture could make it anything else). How does one feel fear and yet no instinct to fight or flee?